# Problem using 2-level pipe when the first program doesn't exit in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Consider this :

```
xinput  --test 11 | grep "button press   1"
```

***11** is my Optical mouse index (could be anything else) and **"button press   1"** means left click.

When I click somewhere in the screen, that shows me this :

```
button press   1
```

No problem so far . But when I wanted to use the output of that as the input to my C program , I noticed that the **stdin** of the program after another level of pipe is always empty :

```
xinput  --test 11 | grep "button press   1" | ./poll_test
```

Here's my **poll_test** code:

```c
/*This is just a program to test polling functionality on stdin.
I've used other programs instead of this as well.
None of them were able to read the stdin */

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int fd;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes_read;
    struct pollfd pfds[1];

while (1) {
        pfds[0].fd = 0;
        pfds[0].events = POLLIN;
        poll(pfds, 1, -1);
        if (pfds[0].revents & POLLIN) {
            bytes_read = read(0, buf, 1024);
            printf("%s\n" , buf);
            if (!bytes_read) {
                printf("stdin closed\n");
                return;
            }
            write(1, buf, bytes_read);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints nothing despite of the clicks.

That is confusing.This is not a normal behavior. When I run this for example:

```
ls | grep a | grep b
```

It shows me the results successfully. The only difference is that the `ls` here exits after it prints out to the **stdout** but that's not the case in the **xinput** version.

I spend a lot of time to write a script to play a beep in the event of a mouse click but that didn't work. So I wanted to use a C program because there's no **polling** functionality in bash.

As far as I know , working of the pipes in bash is something like this :

> The second program (the right one in the pipe statement) gets executed until it wants to **READ** from its **stdin** and it stops going further until there's something to read from the **STDIN**.

With that in mind, the third program in the command I posted should be able to read the output.As it's the case when the first programs exits.

The next step would be to use **libxcb** directly instead of the command **xinput** if pipe problem doesn't work.

I'm totally confused. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** I also tried using an intermediate file descriptor:

```
exec 3<&1
xinput --test 11 | grep -i "button press   1" >&3  | ./poll_test 3>&1
```

but didn't help.And also flushing the stdout forcibly doesn't work either :

```
xinput --test 11 | grep -i "button press   1" ; stdbuf -oL  | ./poll_test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `grep` is changing its buffering behaviour depending on whether the output is a terminal or not. I don't know exactly why this happens, but `--line-buffered` forces it to use line buffering (evaluating the expression as soon as the line ends):

```
xinput --test 11 | grep "button press   1" --line-buffered | ./poll_test
```

Comment: You can also use `stdbuf` if you use something other `grep`.